# System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting Chart AxisLabel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using DataVisualization.Charting chart. I need to set the Y axis label, I m getting the amount but need to add a $ sign to the amount, Datapoint.AxisLabel is working only for X axis.

```
                point = new DataPoint();
                point.AxisLabel = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", Xdate[i]);               
                double result = Convert.ToDouble(results[i]);
                point.YValues = new double[] { (result) };                  
                seriesDetail.Points.Add(point);
```

Plz help me to know where to define Y axis label and how.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example:

```
<asp:Chart runat="server" ID="Chart">
                <legends>                   
                </legends>
                <borderskin></borderskin>
                <series>
                </series>
                <chartareas>
                    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                        <area3dstyle  />
                        <axisy Title="Title of Y axis" >
                            <LabelStyle  />
                            <MajorGrid />
                        </axisy>
                        <axisx Title="Title of X axis">
                            <LabelStyle />
                            <MajorGrid  />
                            <MinorGrid  />
                        </axisx>
                    </asp:ChartArea>
                </chartareas>
            </asp:Chart>
```